# Behat / Mink Step Fail

Tags: testing, bdd, behat, mink

I have a question. I am wondering if there is any way in Behat/Mink to make it run trough the other remaining steps if one step fails. I did a little bit of research and couldn't find the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very much against the common sense implied probably by any testing framework. The only thing you could do is to override existing step definitions and absorb the errors, though your tests will always pass and you wont know whether there are any issues.